# Nanobind: How to use class from another module inside module?

Tags: python, c++, wrapper, nanobind

I currently have several `NB_MODULEs`, and those have some nb:classes which are identical. I'm looking to move those to a common place so that each `NB_MODULE` can use them from the same location, eliminating some duplicate code.

I have created another module called `common_definitions` and added one class there like this:

```
NB_MODULE(common_definitions_ext, m)
{

    nb::class_<example_t>(m, "example_t")
        .def(nb::init<int64_t, int32_t>())
        .def_rw("utc", &example_t::u_utc_time)
        .def_rw("time_zone", &example_t::s32_time_zone);

}
```

Now, I can create such an object from a test case like this:

```
date = common_nb_definitions.example_t(1701340147, 180)
```

However, when I try to assign that to another module:

```
input = another_module.another_module_input()
input.s_date = date
```

It fails like this:

```
 input.s_date = date
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: (): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self, arg: s_example_t, /) -> None
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is that the full error message? What is the type of `s_date`?

Comment: It seems that is not possible or at least very difficult to extend one NB_module with another. I chosen another approach with submodules and therefore original question is not valid anymore. Thanks kiner_shah for the response.